# Correlating large matrix

Tags: matlab, optimization, correlation

I have a matrix with 100000 columns (variables) and 100 rows (observation).
I need to correlate (pearson) all with all.
I use corrcoef as I found it much faster comparing to corr.
When I take a matrix of 25000 columns the operation takes 15 seconds. However when I increase the size to 50000 after several minutes my matlab RAM increases to 16Gb and matlab (including windows) begins to freeze. Any suggestions? Any patent for splitting? Calculating column by columns turns as extremely inefficient...

Thanks for help,
Vadim

Comment: If memory is a constraint I guess doing it in blocks appears tempting. Don't forget that you only need to calculate about half of the blocks due to symmetry! As a sidenote, think carefully whether you really need all individual correlations.

Answer (score 2):

Brute force calculation of such a large array is impossible without a 64 bit version of matlab plus enough memory to store that large array, or storing the array in some other way. You can store the array offline, only bringing in what you need as you use it.

Additionally, if these numbers will always be small integers, then use uint8 or int8, or a logical array, even a single array, all of which will reduce the memory requirements compared to double arrays. Even better if the array is sparse, then use sparse array operations.

An alternative is to use the [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/) (and the [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/)) to harness the memory of several machines simultaneously.  This would allow you to write:

```
matlabpool open <a large number>
x = distributed.zeros( 100000, 100 );
```

See also [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285475) for dealing with big matrices...

Comment: No, my data is not sparse, but I do have 64-bit Matlab with 16Gb RAM. But even this is not enough :( I will check how can I change data type.

Comment: I think that if I split my input matrix to large chunks and then calculate correlations between them it can also work. The problem is that suppose 50.000 variables I split to 25.000 and 25.000. I calculate fast the correlations within split and now I need to calculate between. I can take 25.000 of the first and add let's say 1.000 each time. For 50.000 this should work in reasonable time. Do you think such approach can work in principle ? Thanks